# Contextual styling with selector - first occurrence of element, nth child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here's my current CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/172/

In my first rule, what I want to do is have that style apply only to the "glah" cell.  Basically, for the first occurrence of the target element, apply the style to the third td element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the fact that the `td` you're trying to style has a `rowspan` attribute:

```
tr.pickConsensusBody td[rowspan]:nth-child(3)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFA4p/173/

Comment: what's the technical definition for that element? td[rowspan]

Comment: It's looking for a `td` element that has a `rowspan` attribute. The attribute selector: [http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors).